# Particular loop

Tags: java, for-loop, iteration

Hey, I'm looking to make a loop that takes in this array:

```
String[] arr = new String[3];
arr[0] = "one ";
arr[1] = "two ";
arr[2] = "three ";
```

And outputs:

```
one two three one one two two three three one one one two two two three three three
```

Essentially, I want it to increase the times it displays each array value by one each iteration.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question... try playing with Math.floor

Comment: and I think you meant "new String[3];"

Comment: How you are implementing it? I mean you must have tried it. Right?

Comment: Think about what would happen if you put one for loop inside another.

Comment: Hint - you will need one loop inside another loop. Now go away and attempt to write an answer for yourself.

Comment: @Drew he did put tag Homework.

Comment: @Adeel Ansari my bad I got to the thread afterwards ^^ pity somebody already put the answer, not Ian didn't think how to get to the answer and will get stuck at the next loop he has to write

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
        for (int k=0; k<i; k++) {
            System.out.print(arr[j] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That code will lead to an exception: You are declaring an array of 2 locations and assigning it 3 values. The arr[2] will cause an exception (out of bounds).

Use nested loops to print the content.

Comment: The code that the OP provided, the code that initializes the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
  for(int i=0;i<Array.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j= 0 ;j<Array.length;j++)
                {
                    for(int k=0;k<=i;k++)
                        {
                        System.out.println(""+Array[j]);
                         }
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another method:

```
String[] array = {"One ","Two ", "Three "};
int n = 10;
int counter = 1;

        for(int i =0;i<n;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<array.length;j++){
                String element = array[j];
                for(int k=0;k<counter;k++){
                    System.out.print(element+" ");
                }
            }
            counter++;
            System.out.println();
        }
```